# How do I hide a word in a random number matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, crossword

I am a Python beginner and am stuck here. I have written the following program that generates a matrix of random numbers.

```
def randsq(size):
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            print(random.randint(0,9), end = '')
        print()
```

Is there anyway I can add a function that takes a word from an input parameter and hides it diagonally within the matrix? So if the user inputs 'rain', the output looks like this:

```
r123
1a45
23i4
989n
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does that really count as *hidden* for you?

Comment: @marc_s ,would "integrated" be a better description? sorry, I guess I just used "hidden" because it's not very obvious that there is a word in there.

Comment: @sascha I guess this previous comment from the OP was meant for you

Answer (score 1):

Modified code:

```python
import random
def randsq(word):
    size = len(word)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if i == j:  # we are at a diagonal-value
                print(word[i], end='')  # it's the i-th diag -> choose i-th char
            else:
                print(random.randint(0, 9), end='')
        print()

randsq('Rain')
```

Output:

```
R757
0a91
02i9
757n
```

If you want the user to input this word:

```
word_to_hide = input('Which word to hide? (+enter) ')  # will wait for user-input + enter
randsq(word_to_hide)
```

Comment: That's awesome! I was far from that :/ If I wanted to leave the word up to the user would I just use input() at the end?

Comment: Not necessarily at the end. You can use input to obtain some string which is then the argument to randsq(word). With my code, the matrix-size will automatically adapt.